# How to compile with external Java library jars?

Tags: java, libraries

In Eclipse, I can use the Build Path > Library's > Add External jars option in Eclipse to add an extra library in a jarfile to use. How can I do this without Eclipse?

I'm using a Mac.

Comment: Add the jar file to your classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running javac from the command line, use the -classpath argument.

Comment: So `javac <filename>.java -classpath <path to external jar>`?

Comment: you have to put the command line options first, like `javac -classpath <external.jar> <filename>.java`

Comment: As an aside, if you're getting into territory where you have lots of jars and source files, you might look into a build system like [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org)

Comment: Thanks! But `*.java` is enough for me for now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do in an easy way
type the following command

```
set CLASSPATH=".;[your jar file path]"
```

and then run your file
and for detail reference for setting class path for java and for jar files you can follow the
[link](http://compilr.org/config/set-class-path-from-command-line-java/)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the classpath, with the names of your Jar files. For an example, if your Jar file is **Mail.jar** , edit the '**Path**' variable in **Environment Variables** with the name the location and the name of Mail,jar